# Galaxy On5 not compatible with Adoptable Storage

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage, samsung-galaxy-on5

Samsung Galaxy On5 (MetroPCS)

> - Android OS: 6.0.1 Marshmallow
> - Status: Rooted
> - Recovery: TWRP
> - Framework: Xposed v85.1 (Wanam build)
> - Model: SM-G550T1 (on5ltemtr)

I had installed Root Essentials a couple weeks back, and while fumbling through it, I came across "Adoptable Storage".

***In a nutshell, that's when you format your External SD Card & combine it with your Internal Memory for more space***

After hours upon hours of research, forum trolling, YouTube videos, contacting Samsung, etc..., I've found no working method to allow Adoptable Storage to work on my On5.

Samsung made all their newly released phone's running MM "incapable" of this feature, while all other company device's running MM have full access to it.

There's a loophole for Samsung phone's to obtain Adoptable Storage by way of ADB and Fastboot commands. I've tried that method and followed it step by step, down to the final period. FAILURE. Galaxy S7 & S7 Edges can obtain it by way of ADB/FB along with other Samsung device's, except the On5.

My question after a short-story rundown: is there a 100% working method for the On5 to obtain Adoptable Storage or should I stop searching & close this book?

Comment: DO NOT under any circumstances do the ADB technique on the Galaxy 0n5. It took me, and several other people on XDA nearly 3 days to clear the (insidious) FRP lock that we tripped in doing so. This completely disabled the phone, we were only able to access DL mode.

Answer (score 0):

Great to read you gave Root Essentials a try! We have just updated Root Essentials with a renewed approach to handle those difficult phones just like yours. Version 2.3.1, released on Google Play / XDA / APKMirror, contains this new code.

Feel free to try and do let us know the results! Thomas, dev. Root Essentials.